# Blank desktop problem

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os

On Raspbian, I installed a different desktop environment and selected the wrong one in the terminal and when I rebooted, I went to the MATE desktop environment even though it's not installed.

I tried to right-click for the submenu or reach the terminal, but can't access anything.
It's just the background and the movable mouse cursor.

What can I do to fix this?

No icons, text, menus or anything

Comment: Can you ssh in to the pi from another machine and run `sudo raspi-config` and select command line to get back to a terminal session? If not enabled - power off, pull the card add a file ssh to the /boot partition and reboot (Pi normally checks every time for this file thank goodness)  Does ctl-alt-T work to give you a terminal?  Try adding ` init=/bin/sh` to end of cmdline.txt (note leading space) keep on one line - do on another machine.  Other machine can be the same Pi with a different SD running and original in an USB SD adapter.

Comment: "What can I do to fix this?" What most of the experienced users would do **restore from your BACKUP** - indeed I wouldn't dream of performing such a change without a fresh backup. It is not impossible for an expert to rescue a failure but this is usually more effort and risker than a fresh start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I pressed [ctrl]+[alt]+[f1] to get to the command line, changed the environment code and rebooted. Solved! :D